# NOT IN SQL QUERY SET

Tags: mysql, join

```
###user_name      mobile     product_type###
aaa 12345   1

aaa 12345   2

bbb 56789   2

ccc 23456   2

bbb 56789   1

ccc 23456   1

ddd 11111   1

eee 22222   2
```

my db.table in above format.....where 2 stands for duplicate of 1 (both mobile and name shuold unique) it must have a original product_type 1....I want the record of ##eee 22222   2##..if you notice it doesnt have product_type 1..hope you understand...I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `applications` a where a.product_type=2 and user_name in (select user_name from `partners_applications` where user_name=a.user_name) order by a.user_name
```

I know this is wrong, can you guys pls help me to resolve...

Comment: what result u expect to have? can u post also prtners table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *, count(*) AS counter
          FROM applications
        GROUP BY user_name, mobile) aView
 WHERE product_type = 2 AND counter = 1;
```

Comment: I think this worked for me..i am unable rate this post...it asks for some reputation...

Comment: @user1854007 you can accept [a satisfying answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) though.

Answer (score 0):

i think u looking for this

```
     SELECT * FROM `applications` a 
     INNER JOIN `partners_applications` pa ON pa.user_name=a.user_name 
     WHERE a.product_type=2 
     GROUP BY a.user_name
     ORDER BY a.user_name
```

EDIT

due to your typo fel here my updated answer

```
   SELECT * FROM `partners_applications` a 
   where a.product_type=2 
   and a.user_name not in (select user_name from partners_applications
                    where product_type = 1)
   group by a.user_name
   order by a.user_name
```

[**SQL DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e61745/10)

EDIT2.

well if you have user_name with different telefon number then you can try this

```
   SELECT * FROM `partners_applications` a 
   where a.product_type=2 
   and a.user_name not in (select user_name from partners_applications
                    where product_type = 1)

   order by a.user_name ;
```

[**DEMO SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/392c6/3)

Comment: Sorry for my typo error both are same table it should read as SELECT * FROM `partners_applications` a where a.product_type=2 and user_name in (select user_name from `partners_applications` where user_name=a.user_name) order by a.user_name

Comment: I only need the record of ##eee 22222 2##..if you notice it doesnt have product_type 1..

Comment: this answer is okay...but if you read my post again both username and mobile should match..I dont validated on my initial days..its giving headache to me...

Comment: i have read again your post , i dont understand what u mean by they should match username and mobile. is something else u want in this query to ouput?

Comment: some users mistyped both user name and mobile on product 2 entry...so my db mismatched with type 1 record...as you know name can be same for some users but mobile number not...thats what i mean...

Comment: i have edited my answer EDIT2 , sorry i was not here . hope this what you need , i have made user eee with different telefon number . tell me if this what u need

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I got this right. You want to see all the user_name|mobile pairs that have only one product type equal to 2 (otherwise you would have displayed username `ddd`, right?).

This is the query that does that for you.

```
select user_name, mobile, max(product_type) product_type
from table1
group by user_name, mobile
having count(distinct product_type) = 1 and sum(product_type = 2) = 1
```

Demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17648/1).

Note: I noticed that you wanted to also see the product type in your result. However, that should be unnecessary as the initial condition is that the result have only product_type = 2 records. Anyway, I added it with a `max` function to avoid unnecessary and expensive joins or subqueries.